# Minecraft versions in Feed the Beast

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods, minecraft-feed-the-beast

I've heard various things about the Minecraft version Feed the Beast runs. Some people say it runs 1.5.1, others say it runs 1.4.7. Others still say it *supports the features* of 1.4.7, as if to imply it's actually an older version with mods that emulate the new features of 1.4.7 (not excluding all the mods' other features, of course).

Can anyone clarify which version FTB actually runs? If it is indeed 1.4.7 or later, how is that achieved? IndustrialCraft, RedPower, and perhaps other included mods do not support those newer MC versions, as far as I can tell. So how would FTB make that version work?

I realize that there are multiple modpacks under the FTB banner. But a lot of them seem to include some combination of the big, popular mods like IndustrialCraft and Redpower. These are the ones I'm speaking of.

On a related note, if I wanted to install a lot of the mods in FTB, but *not* actually use FTB, would you recommend a particular Minecraft version? I.e. is there a certain lowest-common-denominator version of MC that's recommended for compatibility with all the big mods in FTB?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All the major modpacks available through the FTB launcher are currently running on Minecraft version 1.4.7. All the mods included in the packs (including IndustrialCraft and Redpower) have natively supported 1.4.7 for quite a while and many of them now support 1.5.

The official packs in the launcher are also going to be staying on 1.4.7 for a while as the current plans of the pack developers are to not officially update the major packs to 1.5 but instead skip to 1.6.

Comment: Thanks. Am I looking in the wrong place for the latest versions? For example, the IC2 wiki lists downloads only as high as 1.4.5 (http://wiki.industrial-craft.net/index.php?title=Download#IndustrialCraft.C2.B2). And the Redpower blog lists 1.4.6 support as "prerelease" (http://www.eloraam.com/download-redpower/). Oddly, both pages are rather old. I'm getting the feeling this stuff has all moved elsewhere. Is that right?

Comment: Maybe, I personally use the launcher to avoid the hassle of having to track down each mod individually.

Comment: Would you, or anyone else, know where some of these mods' newer releases are? Or why they're not listed on the mods' websites? Something about this isn't adding up for me. (Not saying you're wrong. Just that I'm confused.)